# Mssql driver does not report error/exception when using Statement.execute() command

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I was trying to execute multiple lines of SQl using the Statement.execute() method like shown, and I tried to execute something that is obviously going to fail, but no exception is being thrown. Has anyone faced this issue in the past? What am I doing wrong?

```
Statement s = manager.createStatement();
boolean result = s.execute("CREATE TABLE table1(id int, value int, PRIMARY KEY (id));\n" +
                    "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,10);\n" +
                    "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,14);");
```

When I run this, everything looks fine, no error or exception anywhere.

I'm using the `mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre8.jar` driver. Also tried with `mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre8.jar`, no difference.

When I run the same thing using the .executeQuery() method, I get the expected exception regarding the violation of primary key.

Comment: It may be weird, but you'll have to get all result sets for the errors to trigger. I'm personally not a fan of how this works because you're not getting all exceptions in all cases (meaning, all execute methods).

Comment: the sql server handling is a bit weird, sometimes errors are attached to the resultsets. if you do   if (result)
        {
            ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
        }
        else if (s.getUpdateCount() != -1)
        {
            boolean b = s.getMoreResults();
            if (b)
            {
                System.out.println("has results");
            }

        }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute multiple queries, you can use batch method like this:

```
...
            // Step 1: create statement object from connection
            Statement s = con.createStatement();
           
            // Step 2: Create a statement / create table
            String sql1
                = "CREATE TABLE STUDENT(STUDENTID VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,NAME VARCHAR2(20),DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(10))";
 
            // Step 3: Process a query
            // Insert records in the table
            String sql2
                = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S101','JEAN','CSE')";
            String sql3
                = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S102','ANA','CSE')";
            String sql4
                = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S103','ROBERT','ECE')";
            String sql5
                = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S104','ALEX','IT')";
            String sql6
                = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S105','DIANA','IT')";
            s.addBatch(sql1);
            s.addBatch(sql2);
            s.addBatch(sql3);
            s.addBatch(sql4);
            s.addBatch(sql5);
            s.addBatch(sql6);
 
            // Step 4: Process the results
            // execute the sql statements
            s.executeBatch();
...
```

Comment: @TT. I understand but my way a better way I think more clean way

Comment: @TT. do you happen to know of such problems with other databases also ? Also, is it fine if we use executeQuery method here instead. It throws expected error in the described scenaio

Comment: @Thiccasa69 Executequery will get you just one result set. If there are more than one statement in your query, you will only get an error for the first SQL statement. If you are sending scripts with `execute`, you will have to pull all result sets to be sure any exception is triggered should you have a SQL-error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're executing multiple statements, and that means that the SQL server implementation will report results *per statement*.

You will need to use the following to get exception from the second or third statement:

```
boolean result = s.execute("CREATE TABLE table1(id int, value int, PRIMARY KEY (id));\n" +
                    "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,10);\n" +
                    "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,14);");
while (result || s.getUpdateCount() != -1) {
    result = s.getMoreResults();
}
```

If there is a pending exception for the second (or in this case, third) statement, the call to `getMoreResults()` will throw it.

Alternatively, use the JDBC API as it is intended to be used, and execute the statements individually.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should print out **your Boolean result for execute** execute(string) returns a Boolean which I believe will most likely be false!

**The executeQuery(string) must return a "ResultSet"**, so it would throw exception because that is not the type of statement to use in executeQuery.

Any errors of SQL code execution belong to the SQL server, the Java only is reporting the outcome by particular tools it has to check the final outcome such as error code numbers, however, some interaction through the connector is monitored and will assert error as exception as the API docs generally define will occur with particular methods.

Comment: That is not the reason, the problem is that the OP is executing three statements, and each statement has a result. They need to call `getMoreResults()` to get the error for the second or third statement.

Comment: Cheers, but you must admit to use a method (he tried) that returns only resulstet is not to be used for update or insert or delete, there are no ResultSet from update no matter how hard you try.

Comment: -1 is a bit steep, it is basically the answer accord the API docs.(beats me why he didn't use the API docs about the methods, they are compulsory to understand it).

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.